# MVC - Exclude from Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

I have an `enum` which is used in `dropdown` for selection. I don't want to show `1st enum` which is `NA` in my `dropdown`.

How to `exclude` 1 element from `enum`?

```
public enum EmployeeStatus
    {
        NA = 1,
        Active = 2,
        InActive = 3,
        Other = 5
    }

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeStatus, Enum.GetNames(typeof(Models.EmployeeStatus)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }), "--Select Type--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Where`

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(Models.EmployeeStatus)).Where(x => x != "NA")
```